# Lucian and Nami duolane

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm playing Nami support and i found the botlane Nami/Lucian very strong, but i'm wondering something.

If Lucian does the combo `AA + Dash + reset AA + double AA`, does he use all stacks of `Tidecaller's blessing`?
If the combo works, it is preferable to maximaze `Ebb and Flow` or `Tidecaller's blessing`?
He'll slows the enemies ADC or the support and you can `Aqua Prison` one of them.

If you don't know the name of Nami's skill, i give you a like to the wiki [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nami).

Comment: yes all stacks used, max tidecallers

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I made a mistake i uped the other spell. It's very powerfull burst !

Comment: yea but blessing gives alot to lucian. need to practice timing it right though

Comment: @Brian Why not post that as an answer? :D

Comment: @cloudymusic i don't feel like keeping it updated/relevant across patches, feel free to use it and do it yourself though. Also this is my opinion others may benefit more from maxing ebb and flow

Comment: Posting an answer doesn't obligate you to be in charge of keeping it up to date, but up to you, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If Lucian does the combo AA + Dash + reset AA + double AA, does he use
>   all stacks of Tidecaller's blessing?

Yes.

> If the combo works, is it preferable to maximize Ebb and Flow or
>   Tidecaller's blessing?

The problem with Lucian especially in the recent patches is his **low range**. He is constantly in danger's way and therefore, very susceptible to poke bot lanes (e.g. Caitlyn Lulu).

The burst potential for Tidecaller's blessing + Lucian's Kit is immense, but you have to consider :

1. Can Lucian pull it off? You're putting all the damage and work for the ADC, that 1 CC would break off all your damage. (Lulu's W, Annie's stun, etc.)
2. Are you at a position to be aggressive? Are you generally at an advantage?
3. Is the enemy bot lane a sustain comp? (Soraka's heal can nullify your whole combo)

There are some cases when you'd still want Nami to take **Ebb and Flow** for its powerful sustain.

TL;DR,

Tidecaller's is a pretty good skill to max if you're going to be aggressive (kill lane). Ebb and Flow is more for sustain lanes.